# Apache POI Excel Date

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to do automations in Java with Apache POI and I need to convert a date dd-MM-yyyy into the format that Excel saves dates. like 31.12.2022 equals to 44926 in Excel. so I searched a bit and discovered that the number equals the days that have passed between 1.1.1900 and in this example 31.12.2022 so i searched for a function that calculates this but only got some that have irregular differences than from excel. I also tried with ChatGPT but no luck.

```
    Date date1 = new Date(year, month, day);// some date
    Date date2 = new Date(1900,1,1); // some other date
    long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    int differenceDays = (int) (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return differenceDays;
```

I used this code and as I said earlier it'ss not the same result I get in Excel at first I thought it was just a difference of 4 that is always the same so I just added +4 but then I realized that this doesnt work because sometimes its 3 or smth else.

Comment: Which version of Apache POI are you using? Asking because newer versions support java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and you should not use `Date`, which is an old, poorly designed and outdated class (and even if you insisted on `Date`, you should still stay far away from the deprecated and confusing constructors; they have been deprecated for over 25 years for a reason).

Comment: I read that the Excel epoch/baseline is 1899-12-30. And `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(1899, Month.DECEMBER, 30), LocalDate.of(2022, Month.DECEMBER, 31))` does yield your expected 44926. So there is no reason to make it more complicated than this.

Comment: Wow that works. Thank you so much. you said that Date is outdated what shall i use instead?

Comment: For a date without time of day use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). For other date and time purposes use other classes from the same API.

Comment: Also there doesn’t seem to be any reason for you to perform the conversion yourself. An Apache POI `Cell` has [a `setCellValue` method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.time.LocalDate-) that acepts a `LocalDate` and performs the conversion for you.

Comment: Apache POI has a util class for doing the conversion - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html - but it isn't clear why you aren't just using eg `cell.setCellValue(LocalDate)`